# How can I enumerate an expression within $$ ... $$?

Tags: equations, align, enumerate, subequations, mathspec

Can someone help me, I want to enumerate my mathematical expressions that I wrote inside `$$ ... $$`.

```
$$y=f( \sum_{i=1}^{N} w_ix_i+w_0)$$
```

I used `\align` but it doesn't work, I even used `\begin{equation}`

Please help

Comment: See [Why is `\[ … \]` preferable to `$$`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503)

Comment: Are you used to MathJax, where it's indeed permissible to insert line breaks inside a `$$ ... $$` group? Are you using PlainTeX or LaTeX?

Comment: i'm using LaTex not PlainTex

Comment: What do you mean by "enumerate"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{amsmath}


\begin{document}

\begin{align}
y& =f\biggl( \sum_{i=1}^{N} w_ix_i+w_0\biggr), \\
U&=i
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

P.S.: avoid `$$ ... $$`; use `\[ ... \]`  or `\begin{equation} ... \end{equation}` instead.

Comment: ! Paragraph ended before \align was complete. that's what i got when i use your proposition

Comment: @HalaElomrani Definitely not with the code from this answer (as is).  I can confirm that it works.  If you have another problem, please ask a new separate question.

Comment: it's working because you added the seconde ligne but if you keep just the first one , exactly like what i'm asking , it will not , i don"t know why , i'm a beginner user of LaTex

Comment: Also, make sure you don't have blank lines in math mode.

Answer (score 3):

It's not clear what you are looking for.  If you are actually looking for a Plain TeX solution (which the `$$...$$` syntax suggests), use `\eqalignno`.  The third column holds the number.

```
$$\eqalignno{
  y &= f\biggl( \sum_{i=1}^{N} w_ix_i+w_0 \biggr) & (1)
}$$
\bye
```

[image]

You could also use `amstex`.

```
\input amstex
\TagsOnRight
$$\align
  y &= f\biggl( \sum_{i=1}^{N} w_ix_i+w_0 \biggr) \tag{1}
\endalign$$
\bye
```

The output is similar.

Comment: Thank you first, but i'm using LaTex So the both solutions doesn't work

Comment: @HalaElomrani This wasn't clear from the question.